# AngularJS isolate scope how to add to correct parent scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive 'outerDirective', it has children that are directives, and they have children that  are directives. How do I add the grandchildren directives scopes to the correct child directive scope? I hope that makes sense. Here is a fiddle showing the code.  It looks like I need to communicate to a scope method in the child directive rather than the controller instance. http://jsfiddle.net/hcabnettek/DMhUL/
The html is something like this

```
<div class="my-outer-directive">

    <div class="my-inner-directive" id="foo1">

        <div class="my-inner-inner-directive"></div>
        <div class="my-inner-inner-directive"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-inner-directive" id="foo2"></div>
    <div class="my-inner-directive" id="foo3">
       <div class="my-inner-inner-directive"></div>
       <div class="my-inner-inner-directive"></div>
       <div class="my-inner-inner-directive"></div>
       <div class="my-inner-inner-directive"></div>
   </div>
```

I'm expecting foo1 scope, to have a subscriptions property with 2 scopes
foo2 scope, subscription property with 0 scopes, and foo3 have a subscription property of 4 scopes. I believe they are all being added to singleton controller instance. How do I link the inner-inner directives to the appropriate scope.  Something like nested accordions. Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways for child directives to communicate with their parent:

Use the require property on the directive configuration object to gain access to the parent directives controller inside the child, like this:

```
.directive('parent', function() {

  return {
    controller: function() {  
      this.parentFn() {
        //do stuff.
      }
    } 
  }
})

.directive('child', function() {

  return {
    require: '^parent',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
        parentCtrl.parentFn(); //this will execute the parent function here
    }
  }
});
```

Or, pass a function to the child directive in the template like this

```
<child parent-fn=parentFn()></child>

.directive('child', function() {

  return {
    scope: {
      parentFn: '&' // this function is now available on child's scope
    }
  }
});
```

This way its not the parent that gains direct access to its children, but instead the children that gains access to some of the parents methods, hope that helps.

Comment: Yes ai am aware of all these things, unfortunately they are not relevant to the question. Did you take a look at the fiddle? Its using the controller method, the problem is the controller appears to be a singleton. Thanks anyways

Comment: Ok sorry I completely misread your question :) Not sure if I can help then, but I think you might need to set the scope as isolate on both `my-inner-directive` and `my-inner-inner-directive` with `scope: {}` or else they will share the `$scope.subscriptions` property.

Comment: yes I had tried that as well. I think I didnt update the fiddle. Thanks